# ps command: How generate the report of processes but according with only either tty or pts?

Tags: ps, options

Through the `ps --help all` command about the option(s) related with `tty` exists  the following:

```
 -a                   all with tty, except session leaders
  a                   all with tty, including other users
  x                   processes without controlling ttys
```

I know the difference between `tty[1-6]` and `pts/[0...N]`, quickly the former is based on a direct connection through a console and the latter through a remote connection (i.e: `ssh`), correct me if something is wrong

Through Virtual Box for Ubuntu Server, having:

- the 6 tty being logged with 3 different users (2 users in 2 tty, for example user1 logged at tty1 and tty3, user2 logged at tty2 and tty4 and so on)
- 3 SSH connections.

When is executed either `ps a` or `ps -a` commands, in their output - the `TTY` column/header appears with the `tty[1-6]` values as expected, **but** also appears `pts/[0..N]` too. I didn't expect that because `pts` is **not** a `tty`.

Now about the `x` option - not sure if its description indicates/means: all about **not** related with `tty` - for example `pts`. But again appears both, the `tty` (not expected) and `pts` that is expected.

If I am understanding in a wrong way these options, pls correct me.

**Question**

- How generate the report of processes but according with only either `tty` or `pts`? Not both together

Comment: Sometimes it's easier to use `grep` or `awk` or similar on the output.  eg to see all processes on a terminal (tty/pts) you can use `ps aux | awk '$7 ~ /tty|pts/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pts` is used for any [UNIX 98 pseudoterminal](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html), not only remote connections. You’ll see it used for graphical terminal emulators, `screen` or `tmux` sessions, etc.

You mentioned `tty[1-6]`, `tty` can also be a prefix for pseudoterminals, when BSD pseudoterminals are used; you’ll then see `ttyp0` etc. It is also used as a prefix for terminals connected *e.g.* over a serial port (`ttyS0` etc.), USB (`ttyUSB0`) and perhaps others I’m forgetting. There can also be more than 6 VTs.

`ps` doesn’t distinguish between all these. Whatever is a process’ controlling terminal is a terminal.

As a result, the only way to select processes in the way you want to is to either specify individual terminals:

```
ps -t tty1 -t tty2
```

or more generally,

```
ttys=(/dev/tty[123456789]*)
ps "${ttys[@]/#/-t}"
```

etc. (the selection is additive), or post-process `ps`’s output:

```
ps -e | awk '$2 ~ /^tty/'
```

As far as `ps x` is concerned, `x` lifts the restriction requiring that processes have a terminal; it doesn’t limit the selection to processes without a terminal. So `ps …x` will show any processes already selected, plus any other processes which would have been filtered because of their lack of a terminal — in the basic `ps x` case, this is all your processes (the user restriction is still in place).

Comment: `ttys=(/dev/tty[123456789]*); ps "${ttys[@]/#/-t}"` would make more sense. Or better with `zsh`: `function { (( $# )) && ps -t$^@ } /dev/tty<1->(N:t)`